# Integrate Symfony and Joomla, pros and cons

Tags: symfony, joomla, joomla2.5

I have to develop a web application (it’s like a real state backoffice) and I've think about implementing it in Symfony, because my client needs some advanced requirements, like custom reports generation.

But my client also wants the frontend in Joomla, in order to manage templates and some plugin.
My idea is to develop the backend in Symfony, and then show the information on the frontend website using Joomla.

Is this a good decision? Please show me pros and cons, and alternatives are welcome.

I don't know how to access my data from Joomla, I think I have to develop a component to access the data, isn't it?

The data has to be on the same database as Joomla installation, or can it be in another database?

Comment: Which version of symfony and joomla?

Comment: Symfony 2.0.16 and Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just explain to your client that Joomla is a content management system, not the proper tool for backend applications that should manage his business. It's the same as asking: "Oh, i need a logistics management application, but i want to use Gmail to manage it because i'm used to it".

But if you really don't have a choice, or don't want to argue with him, create a REST API with Symfony, having there all your business logic. Then create a simple plugin for Joomla that sends GET's and POST's to your API, either CRUD or just reads.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I'm trying to convince my client that it's better to use Symfony for the front-end also. If I have no success, then I'll give REST a try!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to all the trouble of trying to integrate another system, you might be better off looking through the [Real Estate](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate) extensions on the Joomla Extensions Directory website.

Unless you have major experience with PHP and the Joomla API, creating a component this complex will take you a very long time.

So as a conclusion, this will save you lots of time, will integrate with Joomla and be easy to use.

Comment: I'm experienced in PHP, but not in Joomla API. If I use an existing extension, I'm pretty sure I will not find all of my client requirements (custom report generation, workflow to manage client communications, etc.). If I have to develop this extensions, I feel more comfortable in PHP/Symfony rather than Joomla, and I think is more powerful. I prefer to use Joomla only as a frontend.